# int (binary) to decimal conversion

Tags: c++, io

In c++ when we say `cout << x ; // x is an integer`, we see on the screen the decimal value of it. 
So basically my question is how does the computer/c++ or who ever handles that part, converts from the binary representation to decimal representation. 
It can't be a series of integer division(/) and module(%) operations? Can it?
Sure there is something more efficient for doing so. Or that's just it?

Comment: A series of bitshifts would probably be more effective. I would imagine it's either done on a hardware level or in the iostream, but I'm a bit curious as well. :)

I mean, the number is not converted, it's just displayed differently.

Comment: Read about format specifiers and you will get some idea on lower level of cout working.

Comment: @Jaciq `cout <<` is not bitshift but predefined operator.

Comment: @i486 I know. I meant that if a conversion was to be done in a matter similar to a series of integer divisions, a series of bitshift would probably be more effective.

Comment: Compared to drawing bitmapped images of digits on screen, a few modulo operations take no time at all.

Comment: Why do you think it couldn't be a series of divisions and modulos? That's probably just what it is. Computers are really good at arithmetic like this.

Comment: Writing a function to convert integers to decimal is often a homework problem in first-year programming classes. That's generally how it's done.

Comment: @Jaciq Bitshifts would be more appropriate when converting to octal or hex. Decimal digits don't correspond directly to any bit positions, so `/10` and `%10` are needed.

Comment: @Barmar But the question was on conversion from binary to decimal. :)

Comment: @Jaciq That's my point. Bitshifts won't work for decimal, so why would they "probably be more effective"?

Comment: On older systems, multiplications might be implemented as `x << 3 + x << 1` because it's faster. But modern systems with fast multipliers it might not be as correct as before

Comment: Anyway, it is better to use `printf` instead of `cout` for precise formatting, etc. `cout` may be used for quick tests or diagnostic output.